# Determine network type in iOS 14 Swift 5 without Thirdparty Library

Tags: ios, networking, swift5, ios14, nwpathmonitor

`CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology` is deprecated in iOS 12. so is there any api to get the network type?. we can use NWPathMonitor to know wifi, cellular, ethernet type but not 3g,4g,5g etc. Is there any complete solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> enum Interface {
>     /// A virtual or otherwise unknown interface type
>     case other
>     
>     /// A Wi-Fi link
>     case wifi
>     
>     /// A Cellular link
>     case cellular(CellularType)
>     
>     /// A Wired Ethernet link
>     case wiredEthernet
>     
>     enum CellularType: String, GaugeNetworkType {
>         /// 2G network type
>         case twoG = "2G"
>         
>         /// 3G network type
>         case threeG = "3G"
>         
>         /// 4G network type
>         case fourG = "4G"
>         
>         /// 5G network type
>         case fiveG = "5G"
>         
>         // unknown network type
>         case unKnown
>         
>         var value: String {
>             self.rawValue
>         }
>     }
>     
>     var value: String {
>         switch self {
>         case .wifi:
>             return "Wifi"
>         case .wiredEthernet:
>             return "WiredEthernet"
>         case .cellular(let type):
>             return type.rawValue
>         case .other:
>             return "Other"
>         }
>     }
> }    
>
>
>     func interface(with path: NWPath) -> Interface {
>             if path.usesInterfaceType(.wifi) {
>                 return .wifi
>             } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.cellular) {
>                 return getCellularType(telephonyInfoData)
>             } else if path.usesInterfaceType(.wiredEthernet) {
>                 return .wiredEthernet
>             } else {
>                 return .other
>             }
>         }
>         
>
>      func getCellularType(_ infoData: CTTelephonyNetworkInfoProtocol) -> Interface {
>         guard let carrierTypeName = infoData.cellularType else {
>             return .other
>         }
>         
>         logger.debug(withMessage: "carrierTypeName.. \(carrierTypeName)", category: LogCategory.application)
>         
>         if #available(iOS 14.1, *) {
>             switch carrierTypeName {
>             case CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x:
>                 return .cellular(.twoG)
>             case CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD:
>                 return .cellular(.threeG)
>             case CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE:
>                 return .cellular(.fourG)
>             case CTRadioAccessTechnologyNRNSA,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyNR:
>                 return .cellular(.fiveG)
>             default:
>                 return .cellular(.unKnown)
>             }
>         } else {
>             switch carrierTypeName {
>             case CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x:
>                 return .cellular(.twoG)
>             case CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB,
>                  CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD:
>                 return .cellular(.threeG)
>             case CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE:
>                 return .cellular(.fourG)
>             default:
>                 return .cellular(.unKnown)
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology was deprecated in iOS 12, but only because iOS 12 introduced multisim support; hence there is no single radio access technology.

The same information is available in the dictionary CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology.

In most cases, you can just use CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.dataServiceIdentifier]